# PeakWorkingSet64, doesn't give me the proper result

Tags: .net, memory

I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process. PeakWorkingSet64 to get the current memory usage of a process.
This process can reach 8, 10 and even 12GB (don't ask).
My problem is that when I query the process PeakWorkingSet64, it works fine until it rests at 4096mb.

My code is:

`p.Refresh();`

int m = (int)(p.PeakWorkingSet64 /(float) 1024 /(float) 1024);

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: I know you said don't ask, but what's 12GM? What do you expect `m` to be for 12GM?

Comment: How much physical memory do you have?

Comment: 12gm was a mistake - fixed it to 12gb

Comment: Does it rise to 4096 and stops, i.e. does it ever report more than 4096?

Comment: No Never, even when the task manager reports much more

Comment: I'll wage a dollar on: "this is actually a 32-bit process".

Comment: I assure you, as the one who wrote the process, and the one who planned it's memory usage - or the one who bought 24gb of ram to that machine - it is a 64 bit process :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shot in the dark...

You're maxing out at 4GB, but you have 24GB of physical memory. 4GB is the maximum amount of user address space a 32bit process has on a 64bit Windows OS. Try running the program as a 64bit process explicitly. My hunch is that it is running as a 32bit process.

> VS: Project Properties -> Build -> Platform target: x64

**Update**

After setting my platform to x64, the following code on my system exceeds a 4GB working set. It doesn't get much above that as I am testing on a system with 6GB of memory, and there just isn't enough memory to go past ~4.2GB. I do have a server with 24GB of memory, but I am reluctant to hose it for this test! :)

I'm guessing in your comment when you say you're seeing 12GB ram usage on your system with your program, that this is total *virtual memory* usage, and not *physical memory* usage. PeakWorkingSet64 refers to physical memory.

I have placed a few fiddles in the code to ensure that generated data is being touched so that it is kept hot and in physical memory and not paged out (paged out memory is not included in working set figures as it is in the paging file, and not in actual physical memory). Windows will aggressively page memory to disk if it is not being touched.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Is64=" + (Marshal.SizeOf(IntPtr.Zero) == 8));

        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        List<int[]> data = new List<int[]>();

        while (true)
        {
            int[] buffer = new int[1024 * 1024 * 128]; //<- 0.5GB

            data.Add(buffer);

            int touch = 0;

            foreach (var b in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
                {
                    touch += b[i];
                }
            }

            p.Refresh();

            int mb = (int)(p.PeakWorkingSet64 / (float)1024 / 1024);

            Console.WriteLine("ignore" + touch);

            Console.WriteLine(mb + "MB");

            Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
        }
```

Output:

> ignore0
>   524MB
>   ignore0
>   1055MB
>   ignore0
>   1560MB
>   ignore0
>   2074MB
>   ignore0
>   2587MB
>   ignore0
>   3101MB
>   ignore0
>   3615MB
>   ignore0
>   4132MB
>   ignore0
>   4188MB

**Important Note**

Make sure that the process that uses the PeekWorkingSet64 is a 64-bit process. To my surprise a 32-bit process that tries to get the PeekWorkingSet64 of another 64-bit process, will get only 4096MB as its max memory usage, even if the monitored process is 64-bit and holds more physical memory than that.

Comment: +1: Yeah, that would have been my guess too. However, the OP stated that the process *can* reach 8 to 12 GB. If that however never happened, but was only an estimation, then yes, that is good call.

Comment: @Christian I am assuming the OP is seeing 8 and 12GB of Virtual Memory, whereas PeakWorkingSet64 returns *physical* memory.

Comment: But Virtual Memory would have the same restriction (~4GB) for a 32bit process, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Christian You are quite right thinking about it - now I'm confused! Not sure where the 12GB is coming from, 4GB would be the total available address space. I have removed my edit.

Comment: No worries, given the information available it is still the most likely answer. ;-)

Comment: My process runs as 64bit process, and uses around 12gb of ram. So our answer doesn't help me - try it, create a process that uses such memory and view it using this property, let me know what you get. thanks

Comment: ps
sorry for the late response, I was abroad :)

Comment: Found the problem.
What I didn't properly mention is that I had two processes. One that runs the actual task, and consumes the memory, and another that monitors it.
With your permission I'll edit your response.
The process that did the monitoring was 32bit, once I turned the monitor process to be 64 bit, it monitored the second process properly.

Comment: @Noam Ah IC missing details. You have my permission to edit, np. Cheers. Give me shout when you've done and I'll action it.

Comment: I just did, it's waiting for a peer review

Comment: @Noam That sounds like a .Net bug - interesting.

Comment: I think they'll say it's debatable :)

Answer (score 0):

Working set is the amount of physical memory actually visible to the application. Windows is all the time stealing pages from all running processes. It will sit on them for a while and if you try to access them, you get them back (this is called a soft fault).

If others need the memory, your pages are written to the swapfile, zeroed, and reused.

So the physical memory in use by your application can be larger than the working set. The pages "borrowed" by windows are not counted.

Windows has a per process limit on a working set. For 32 bit apps this was 1.3gb. You can query this in process explorer. Just maybe for 64 bit this value is 4gb, i dont know. For the process you describe it could be worthwhile to raise this limit so windows stops trying to trim your process memory footprint.

If you want to contol your memory use, you wantto look at the total virtual memory in use by your process.